# LED driver identification needed

Tags: led-driver

Can someone identify IC "U1" in the below LED lamp PCB?
I've tried to google the identifiers but didn't find anything :-(

It's an 18 W lamp for 240 V AC, and according to the customer it's the second lamp within a few weeks that blew up (obviously fuse FS1 triggered after U1 experienced a "thermal anomaly").

What could be wrong? U1 simply overloaded? Wrong driver concept at all?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Sounds like you aren't the designer/manufacturer, but a reseller of a product. Can you just contact your supplier chain to ask for a root-cause determination? And is this just the one customer experiencing this difficulty? Or more than one? Am I misreading the situation?

Comment: @periblepsis: Neither nor. I'm just the one who was asked to "have a look" by that customer (an old lady from the neighborhood). I recommended her to bring it back to the shop, but am anyway interested in the root cause of the failure.

Comment: Understood and thanks.

Answer (score 7):

It's hard to read the markings, but it seems to be a [Kiwi Instruments KP18106WPA](https://datasheet.lcsc.com/lcsc/2104131812_Kiwi-Instruments-KP18106WPA_C2692496.pdf) LED driver.

[image]

[image]

(Source: [lcsc.com](https://www.lcsc.com/product-detail/LED-Drivers_Kiwi-Instruments-KP18106WPA_C2692496.html))

Comment: Nice. +1 Linear LED driver chip with integrated 800V bridge rectifier.. for 3 or 4 cents.

Comment: Thanks! 
RCS is 10 Ohm. With V_RCS being 600mV typically, this means I = 60 mA, correct? This would be maximum current, but not outside the specification. Maybe the heat slug was not soldered? But the datasheet does also mention a thermal derating function... then I guess it's just poor silicon quality?